# Why is VS 2010 listening on UDP port 8976?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Why is VS 2010 listening on UDP port 8976? On my Win 7 OS I see that "devenv.exe" listens on UDP port 8976, but I can't seem to find anything in the documentation on what its for.

Edit:
It might be one of my add-ons, perhaps?

- VS GIT extentions
- Resharper
- .NET Reflector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it was the JetBrains Resharper add-on that was the guilty culprit, when I uninstalled it the listening port went away.

Comment: Just wondering, have you installed it back since then, or was it a kind of critical requirement of yours to make sure that the plug-in executes no network activity?

Comment: @gorohoroh I will re-install it. I was afraid it was a root-kit of some kind, or a virus. I don't like software installing un-documented listening ports that are active 24/7 on my system.

Comment: Fair enough. Will add a request to document all possible network activity executed by R#

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you ever find out why R# listens on this port?  I keep getting weird lockups in VS and when I analyze my wait chain it complains about waiting on Network IO.  This seems to be the problem and if possible I would love to disable it without uninstalling R# completely.

Comment: @AdamPlocher If I did get a answer from Jetbrains then I've forgotten by now, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Inge, it seems to have something to do with their license check. I'm not totally sure that was my problem, but I did a factory reset for R# and my problem seems to be fixed now.

Comment: @AdamPlocher If it is, then they don't need to have it open 24/7 but should instead do a check when Visual Studio starts and quickly close the network socket once the license assertion has completed imo.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Resharper is constantly using this port to verify license information, such as multiple programs using same license at the same time.